# Basic Repeatable Component Animation Example in React Native

Tags: react-native, animation

**UPDATE: 12/8/19**

Thanks to @Lenoarod's pointers, I was able to successfully implement the behavior I was going after.

I am posting the complete solution to give back to the SO community. If you are new to React Native like me and are looking for a lightweight ready-to-go example for basic component animation, do take a look :)

Here is a link to my [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kcdev/reset-animation?session_id=snack-session-vb5JqKBs7). Happy coding!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Animated.timing` as the document says: *Animates a value along a timed easing 
 curve.*; so when the animation finish,  the `animatedVaule` is equal to the `toValue`, so you have to re-set the `animatedValue`.

you define `animatedValue` is global, I suggest you define it in the component.

as for why after the 1 seconds, the component is not hidden; because the default function does not bind this. you try to use the arrow function. then check if `this.setState` is called and `showMessage` is set `false`.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0)
      this.state={
         fontSize: 1,
         isVisible: false,
      }
   }
}

animateText() {

 this.animatedValue.setValue(0) 
 this.setState({showMessage: true})

 Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 250,
      easing: Easing.ease
    }).start(() => {
      // Animation Complete
    })

 setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        showMessage: false,
      })
    }, 1000)
}
```

With a regular function, this represents the object that calls the function; With an arrow function this represents the owner of the function if you want to know more about the arrow function, you can see this [site](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp)

in the end, I find the animation in the snack that it is slow. so I suggested you use [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)

Comment: Hey thank you for your fix suggestion and link to your resource (this whole "arrow" and "bind" business is all very new to me). Thanks to your fix, the message now properly hides after `setTimeout()` is called. However, the animation is still not working (it's just simply 'blinking' instead of actually showing the original animation).

Comment: @ElSushiboi, I update the answer, try to use `setValue`

Comment: So when I moved `animatedValue` inside the `AnimatableText` class the way you did, I get an error: "animatedValue is not defined" in the StyleSheet. Any workaround?

Comment: if you use it into the stylesheet, one way define it into the `render` method. if you don't want to do that or your style is complex. you can use `animatedValue` to global. it chooses to depend on your situation

Comment: I've moved animatedValue inside render, and I am no longer getting the "animatedValue is not defined" error. However, now nothing happens when the button is tapped. I've updated the snack as well, so if you can point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd be indefinitely grateful.

Comment: @ElSushiboi, I have update the answer. in the snack, it worked, but it is slow

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly the behavior I was looking for. I shall study the code carefully to enrich my understanding. Thanks a lot!